# Cannot set up a project in Firebase using CLI tools

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, cloud

```
=== Project Setup

First, let's associate this project directory with a Firebase project.
You can create multiple project aliases by running firebase use --add,
but for now we'll just set up a default project.

? Please select an option: Create a new project
i  If you want to create a project in a Google Cloud organization or folder, please use "firebase projects:create" instead, and return to this command when you've created the project.
? Please specify a unique project id (warning: cannot be modified afterward) [6-30 characters]:
 amspsingh-project-notes
? What would you like to call your project? (defaults to your project ID) Notes Project
× Creating Google Cloud Platform project

Error: Failed to create project. See firebase-debug.log for more info.`
```

I have followed the necessary steps to setup the firebase CLI, have authorised it correctly with my account(as far as I know, can be wrong)
However I cannot create GCP project, please help me out with this